# Consume wcf service using HttpWebRequest c#

Tags: c#, wcf, httpwebrequest

```
HttpWebRequest req = null;
HttpWebResponse res = null;

const string url = http://localhost/MyService/EService.svc/CreateMethod";

req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

req.Headers.Add("App", "Application");
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes("{ itemlist: 'sasfs' }");
req.ContentLength = data.Length;

res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = res.GetResponseStream();
var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

string txt = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
streamReader.Close();
streamReader.Dispose();

responseStream.Close();
responseStream.Dispose();
```

I have to use above code to consume service, but i am getting different errors-
1) You must provide a request body if you set ContentLength>0 ....
What is the code I am missing exactly here.

Comment: You never set the content of the request.

Comment: Can you please give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing few lines of code. You only setting ContentLength but you do not write content.

```
req.ContentLength = data.Length;

//Write request data(setting content of request)
Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
reqStream.Close();

res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Now If I want to add Parameters then ?

Comment: Then you probably need to format your url. Look at [this example](http://www.stickler.de/en/information/code-snippets/httpwebrequest-post-data.aspx)

Comment: I have tried this code but i am getting error-
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error
In below line.
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

Comment: catch exception is generated- The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Comment: Any inner exceptions? Well this error basically points you to look at the server side and might be that you request was wrong. So debug your server to see what is wrong. Also enable [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to see more details.